# How to tell if I am running the latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded Ubuntu into VirtualBox running Linux. My main computer is an iMac running OS X10.9.5 When I go into VB and check my settings it says that I am running Ubuntu 64 bit. Just want to know if I am running the late test version and if not how do I upgrade. I also have download Vagrantup and am unable to get it to work and configure my Linux virtual OS

Thank you for any help.

Maureen

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Kosmiczne_Konsoli will give you your current version. If you also want to check for latest version on ubuntu servers do:

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

Upgrade:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

And If you want to upgrade to the latest development version (not recommended) you can also try:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Before attempting upgrade check the community doc's for upgrading Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two ways that you can check what version of Ubuntu you're running. One way is through Unity and the other, through the terminal.

Through Unity:

1. Open System Settings
2. Click on Details

You should see the version of the OS underneath the Ubuntu logo. In the lower-right part of the screen, you will also see a button telling you "install updates" or "System Up-To-Date". If you see "System Up-To-Date" then you're running the latest version. If you see "Install updates", click on the button to launch software updater.

Once software updater is opened, you should see a screen similar to this:
[image: Ubuntu Software Updater]

(Ignore the objects being updated in the picture, that's just an example.)

Follow the updater's instructions to update

Through terminal:

1. Open the Terminal (keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+T)
2. Enter the command lsb_release -a

Your version will be shown on the Description line.

Hoped this helped :)